# Java: using constructors in calculations, output always 0?

Tags: java, constructor

I recently started using constructors in my java programs. the following program converts currencies Euro to TL. Everything in the program seems correct to my eye, however, the output is always 0 when the program is compiled and ran. I'm guessing the problem is to do with values not being received from the default constructor?

```
import java.io.*;
class tleuro
{ 
    double euro;
    double tl;
    
    
    tleuro()
    {
        double euro = 7;
        double tl = 0.14;
    }

    void convert()throws IOException
    {
        
        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("please select (euro to tl) or (tl to euro)");
        System.out.println("(1) Euro to tl");
        System.out.println("(2) Tl to euro");

        int choice =  Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter euro amount");
                double euroamount = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
                euroamount = (euroamount*tl);
                System.out.println("You're tl amount is "+euroamount);

            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter tl amount");
                double tlamount = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
                tlamount = (tlamount*euro);
                System.out.println("You're euro amount is "+tlamount);

            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        tleuro ob = new tleuro();
        
        ob.convert();
        

    }
}
```

Comment: You're not initialising your fields in your constructor. You're declaring two new local variables.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor initialized two local variables that **hide** the data members, so they remain with their default values, `0.0`.

Remove the variable declaration, and you should be fine:

```
tleuro() {
    // Use the members instead of declaring local variables
    euro = 7;
    tl = 0.14;
}
```

As a side note, if `euro` and `tl` aren't ever modified, you could declare them as `static final` members, instead of initializing them per instance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare the instance variables as doubles in the constructor. Just leave that bit off and you should be fine.

```
import java.io.*;
class tleuro
{
double euro;
double tl;


public tleuro()
{
    euro = 7;
    tl = 0.14;
}
```